# Am i unsubscribing correctly from Renderer2's .listen function?

Tags: angular, angular-renderer2

I am adding multiple listeners to elements generated by render2.

I am doing something like this,

```js
unlistenCallbacks:any[] = [];

.....
const unlistenCallback = this.renderer.listen( ...... );
this.unlistenCallbacks.push(unlistenCallback);
....

ngOnDestroy(){
 this.unlistenCallbacks.forEach(cbk => cbk());
}
```

Is this a good way for disposing of all the handlers?

Comment: Why wouldn't you test this yourself for example with console logs? Also if you were to search SO, you would find an answer ;)

Comment: I cannot know if those callbacks are getting called, if i use it that way. I can't use a console log inside the functions. I can only console log the foreach.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to console log in `listen`?

Comment: The console log would be called when the event that i'm listening to is fired. The callback that i'm passing to the listen function, is not the same to the one returned by it. As for as i know from the docs, the callback returned is only used to dispose of the handler.

Comment: This is what the callback returned by the renderer looks like `() => this.removeEventListener(element, eventName, callback)); `

Comment: Simple way to debug... `this.renderer2.listen(document, 'click', () => console.log('click'));` navigate away from page, navigate back. See if the console logs increment.

Comment: #feelingDumb right now :) thanks. Overthinking it ...    EDIT: So yes, i was disposing correctly.

Comment: Yes you were, but I didn't want to say that instantly when it could be debugged ;) Sometimes we overthink, I know I do it a lot :D